# primefaces subtable checkbox not updated

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a datatable with a few colums of data and 1 column with a checkbox. When checking some checkboxes and afterwards submitting the whole form. The model in my bean is updated and I can see what checkbox (row) is checked. 
But I had to change the design and now I'm using subtables. (so I can group some info). Now the model is not updated when I submit the form. So when looping the datatable values, all checkboxes are false, while I did checked some on the page. How can I solve this?

I'm using primefaces 3

I fill superlist inside loadreports. And when clicking button I call downloadZip and I loop over the superlist to see if checkbox is checked and then I can add a document to a zip file.

Here is my bean

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getSuperList() throws MWSException {
    getLog().debug("getSuperList()");
    if (superList == null) {
        loadReports();
    }
    return superList;
}


private void loadReports() throws MWSException {
    DocumentManager dm = new DocumentManager(getWA().getMwsProxy());
    IMWSDocument[] list = dm.getDocumentHistory(getWS().getUser(), getWS().getUser().getCustomerPartnerId(),
            WebConstants.BUSINESSPARTNER, WebConstants.PUBLISHSTRATEGYENUMIDS, dateFrom, dateTo, null, null, template);

    ArrayList<Object> typeObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
    superList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    Set<Integer> setType = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Object> tempType = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String tempTypeName = "";
    Integer tempTypeId = null;

    for (IMWSDocument d : list) {

        if (type == null || d.getTypeId().equals(type)) {
            if (!setType.contains(d.getTypeId())) {

                if (setType.size() > 0) {
                    tempType = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    tempType.put("typeName", tempTypeName);
                    tempType.put("typeId", tempTypeId);
                    tempType.put("typeObject", typeObject);
                    superList.add(tempType);
                    typeObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
                }
                setType.add((Integer) d.getTypeId());
                tempTypeName = d.getType();
                tempTypeId = d.getTypeId();

                HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp.put("checked", false);
                temp.put("id", d.getId());
                temp.put("name", d.getName());
                temp.put("dateCreated", d.getDateCreated());
                temp.put("fileName",
                        d.getDirPath().substring(d.getDirPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, d.getDirPath().length()));
                temp.put("typeId", d.getTypeId());
                temp.put("type", d.getType());
                temp.put("templateId", d.getTemplateId());
                temp.put("template", d.getTemplate());

                typeObject.add(temp);

            } else {

                HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp.put("checked", false);
                temp.put("id", d.getId());
                temp.put("name", d.getName());
                temp.put("dateCreated", d.getDateCreated());
                temp.put("fileName",
                        d.getDirPath().substring(d.getDirPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, d.getDirPath().length()));
                temp.put("typeId", d.getTypeId());
                temp.put("type", d.getType());
                temp.put("templateId", d.getTemplateId());
                temp.put("template", d.getTemplate());

                typeObject.add(temp);

            }

        }
    }
    tempType = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    tempType.put("typeName", tempTypeName);
    tempType.put("typeId", tempTypeId);
    tempType.put("typeObject", typeObject);
    superList.add(tempType);

    rowCount = superList.size();

}

public void DownloadZip(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, MWSException {

    int BUFSIZE = 4096;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    String tempPath = SiteConfig.getInstance().get("file.dir.temp");

    // RFC says 'attachment'. Unfortunately, IE has a typo so we set "attachement"
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"reports.zip\"");

    DocumentManager dm = new DocumentManager(getWA().getMwsProxy());

    // Stream to the requester.
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];

    File tempdir = new File(tempPath + File.separator + getWS().getUser().getSignOn() + "_" + new Date().getTime());

    tempdir.mkdir();

    File tempFile = new File(tempdir.getPath() + File.separator + "reports_temp.zip");

    ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
    try {
        // Create the ZIP file
        // String outFilename = "outfile.zip";

        // Compress the files
        for (HashMap<String, Object> item : superList) {
            for (Object reportItem : ((ArrayList<Object>) item.get("typeObject"))) {
                HashMap<String, Object> report = ((HashMap<String, Object>) reportItem);
                if ((Boolean) report.get("checked")) {

//this is always false. 
....
```

And here is the jsf page

```
<p:dataTable id="reportlisttable" var="listItem" value="#{reportList.superList}"     cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                        rowClasses="row1,row2" styleClass="data" headerClass="header" columnClasses="col" width="100%"
                        emptyMessage="#{msg.all_lists_no_records_found}" paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,50,100"
                        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  #{msg.all_lists_numberOfRowsDisplayed_label} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">               


                        <p:subTable var="report" value="#{listItem.typeObject}">  
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                  #{listItem.typeName}   
                </f:facet> 

                            <p:column id="column_select" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox name="selectColumn" value="#{report.checked}" />
                            </p:column>

                    <p:column id="id" sortBy="#{report.id}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.reportlist_id}" />
                                </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{report.id}"/>
                          </p:column>

                        <p:column id="date" sortBy="#{report.dateCreated}" parser="date">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.reportlist_date}" />
                                </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{report.dateCreated}">
                            <mw:convertDateTime />
                        </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="name" sortBy="#{report.name}" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.reportlist_reportname}" />
                                </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{report.name}"/>
                        </p:column>
</p:subTable>               
                    </p:dataTable>

                    <t:div id="download">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
                            <t:graphicImage url="${path.staticRootUrl}images/arrow_compare.gif" hspace="15"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="${msg.reportlist_download}" actionListener="#{reportList.DownloadZip}" styleClass="button" ajax="false"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </t:div>
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: no, I added some javascript to fill a list with id's of checkboxes that are selected. And I pass that id to my bean. But maybe with PF 6 this is solved?